# How do I get the Likelihood of this Bayesian parameter $\theta$ in the following conditional equation?

Tags: probability, statistics, bayes-theorem, parameter-estimation

The intenisty (hazard) function is:
$\lambda$(t|$\theta$) 

And the function of t is:
$f(t| \theta)$ = $\dfrac{\lambda(t|\theta)}{1-S(t)}$ 
Where $1-S(t)$ is $F(t) = P(0 < t < T]$

The log likelihood is: (**what I want to get**)
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textrm{log}\mathcal{L} (\theta) & = 
 \sum_{i=1}^{N} \textrm{log}\lambda(t_i - \theta) - \int_{0}^{T} \lambda(t|\theta)dt 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

This is taken from the Seismic data Analysis for Taiwan by Fan and Kuo, they show those equations but they don't explain how they got there. I have tried Bayes rule to get $\lambda(\theta|t)$ so I can get the Likelihood, but what I get is:

From Bayes:
$\lambda(\theta|t) = \dfrac{\lambda(t|\theta) f(\theta)}{f(t)} $

Replacing $f(t)$ by the above equation (and doing a bit of algebra):

$\lambda(\theta|t) = \dfrac{\lambda(t|\theta)f(\theta)}{\lambda(\theta)} - \dfrac{\lambda(t|\theta) f(\theta) S(t)}{\lambda(\theta)}$

Am I getting somewhere or am I even on the right track? Any advice anywone? Thanks for ur time!

Comment: I at first made a lot of edits to the question, but then decided to leave some of it as it was to keep from changing the intent of the question too much. There is some notational stuff and $\LaTeX$ formatting that needed fixed, though.

Comment: I think the log likelihood is incorrect. If you have $\lambda(t) = h(t)$, and let $H(t) = \int_{0}^t h(t) dt$ be the cumulative hazard function, then $f(t) = h(t)e^{-H(t)}$ (see https://web.stanford.edu/~lutian/coursepdf/unit1.pdf)

Following along with that, the log likelihood is:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
 \textrm{log}\prod_{i=1}^N f(t_i) &=\sum_{i=1}^N \textrm{log}f(t_i) \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^N[\textrm{log}h(t_i) - H(t_i)] \\
& =  \sum_{i=1}^N[\textrm{log}\lambda(t_i|\theta) - \int_{0}^{t_i}\lambda(t|\theta)dt]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I think that's correct.

Comment: That expression is also consistent with expression 7.7 in these notes:
http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7.pdf

Those notes are for censored data, but because we aren't censoring set $d_i =1$ for all $i$, and in that situation the formulas are the same.